# Optionally daemonize a Python process

Tags: python, daemon

I am looking into daemonization of my Python script and I have found some libraries that can help: `daemonic`, `daemonize` and `daemon`. Each of them have some issues:

- [daemonic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonic/0.6) and [daemonize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize/2.2.1) will terminate when they cannot create the PID file. daemonic will not even log or print anything. Looking into the code, they actually call `os.exit()`. I would like an exception or other error message, so I can fallback to running my code in the foreground.
- [daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) [doesn't even install correctly](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonic/0.6) for Python 3. And seeing the last commit was in 2010, I don't expect any updates soon (if ever).

How can I portably (both Python2 and 3) and optionally (falling back to running in foreground) create a daemonized Python script? Of course I could fallback to using the `&` operator when starting it, but I would like to implement [PEP3143](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/).

Answer (score 1):

I am using two solutions

- based on `zdaemon`
- based on `supervisor`

Both packages are written in Python and are daemonizing anything, what can be run from command line. The requirement is, that the command to be run is running in foreground and not trying to daemonize itself.

`supervisor` is even part of Linux distributions and even though it comes in a bit outdated version, it is very well usable.

Note, that as it controls general command line driven program, it does not require python version being matched with the controlled code.